# change() for appended select doesn't work

Tags: jquery, select

I've jQuery function on change for a select element:

```
$("#category").change(function(){
    $("table[id=advance_search]").append("<tr id='item_type'></tr>");
    $("tr[id=item_type]").append("<td class='field_input'><select id='type'><option value='1'>One<option><option value='2'>Two<option></select></td>");
});

$("tr[id=item_type]").children(".field_input").delegate("select[id=type]", "change", function() {
    console.log("change");
});
```

When I change value on `select#type`, string "change" doesn't show in console.
Can anyone help me?

---

Edited, for adding `<td class='field_input'>` as children of `$("tr[id=item_type]")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is because `change()` (and all other event handler shortcuts) are bound on page load, yet your element is added dynamically well after this. Instead you need to use `delegate()` to attach the events to this element after it's appended.

```
$("tr[id=item_type]").delegate("select[id=type]", "change", function() {
    console.log("change");
});
```

Or, if you're using jQuery 1.7+ you can use `on()`:

```
$("tr[id=item_type]").on("change", "select[id=type]", function() {
    console.log("change");
});
```

You may want to amend the `select` element you're appending here though, as it has an ID, which could be easily duplicated if it's appended multiple times, which would render the page invalid.

Comment: hei, I missed an element <td>. As a children from $("tr[id=item_type]"), I've use this syntax: $("tr[id=item_type]").children(".field_input").delegate("select[id=type]", "change", function() {
    console.log("change");
}); but it still can't work, can you help me,.?

Comment: the syntax is wrong and it should be: $("tr[id=item_type]").on("change", "select[id=type]", function() {
    console.log("change");
}); So, event name comes first and then you must specify the selector you're about to append later on. See http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks @Ewout. I didn't get any of the comment notifications to update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe with [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function, because when you subscribong with `change` element doesn't exists in DOM and jQuery can't find it.

```
$("select[id=type]").on('change', function(){
     console.log("change");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

because you add it dynamicly you have to use the `live` or `delegate` event

```
$("select#type").live('change', function() {
    console.log('change');
});
```

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated. The preferred methods are now `delegate()` for <jQ1.7, otherwise `on()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("select[id=type]").on("change",function(){
    console.log("change");
});
```

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

source:http://api.jquery.com/live/